# How can solve this differential equation (fourth equation )?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve this differential equation?

$$
 \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{y}+\frac{3F}{y^2})}\sqrt{\frac{A}{y}+\frac{B}{y^2}+\frac{C}{y^4}+\frac{D}{y^5}+E}
$$

where $A,B,C,D,E,F$ are constants.

Comment: It hurts to even look at it. May I ask how did you encounter such Evil?

Comment: what i do this is mathematical life :(

Comment: Numerically!${}{}{}$

Comment: analytically if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{dy}{dx}=F(y)$, have you tried to solve $\frac{dy}{F(y)}=x$?

Comment: I have tried but noway for me :(